# Cannot read property 'serialize' of null

Tags: jquery

Am getting the error `Cannot read property 'serialize' of null` when i perform a post in my script, in my chrome's console.

my code is as below:

```
 $.post('myfile.php', $('#form_id').serialize(), function(datax){
        $('html').load(datax);
        return false;
 });
```

Kindly tell me where am going wrong.

Comment: You're not showing any HTML, but I'm guessing you don't have an element with an ID of `form_id`.

Comment: @AdrianWragg That still shouldn't result in `$('#form_id')` being null, though. Should return a jQuery object that just contains no matching elements.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist You are right, but I don't know the ins and outs of `.serialize()`; it may well be checking that there is at least one item being returned.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using and where are you loading it from?

Comment: ver 1.11.1. Am loading it in the `<head> </head>` tags @AnthonyGrist

Comment: Could you also post the part of code where the error is thrown? Because unless I'm mistaken this part tries to call a method, not read a property. The only way I can think of to get this message is set `jQuery.fn = null;`(but then nothing would work) or some internal jQuery bug.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
 var $ = jQuery;
  $.post('pesapal_iframex.php', $('#hikashop_pesapal_form').serialize(), function(datax){
   $('html').load(datax);
   return false;
   });
 </script>`  Thats the whole of it @René

Comment: @HappyPatrick Why do you have `var $ = jQuery;` in there? Are you loading something else (not jQuery) that also uses the $ shorthand?

Comment: no. Just jQuery. @AnthonyGrist

Comment: @HappyPatrick Hm, ok. Can you post the HTML for the `<script>` tag you use to load jQuery? Are you hosting a copy yourself or loading from a CDN?

Comment: Hosting a copy myself.  `<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`  the file is being referenced nicely without 404s @AnthonyGrist

Comment: @HappyPatrick Try using `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` instead and see if you get the same error?